# Lemma to Prove Euclid's Lemma (a and c integers and t the smallest positive integer such that c | at, then t | c)

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, divisibility

I came across a proof of Euclid's Lemma from [https://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/euclids_lemma.pdf](https://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/%7Emate/misc/euclids_lemma.pdf) that used another lemma to assist in the proof:

> Let a and c be positive integers and let t be the smallest positive integer such that c | at. Let b be a positive integer such that c | ab. Then t | b. In particular, t | c.

Their proof goes as follows:

> Assume t ∤ b; let q and r be such that b = tq + r and 1 ≤ r < t. Then
> ab = atq + ar.
> As c is a divisor of the left-hand side and of the first term on the right-hand side, it follows that c is also a
> divisor of the second term on the right-hand side; i.e., c | ar. This, however, contradicts the minimality of t.
> This contraction shows that t | b. Since we have c | ac, this assertion with c = b shows that t | c holds.

I understand why `t|b` by contradiction. What I don't understand is how they assert `c|ac`, and that `c=b`, and how that leads to being able to assert that `t|c`. Does anyone have any insight into their logic that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand that if $\color{green}t$ is the smallest positive integer such that $\color{blue}{c} \mid a\color{green}t$, and $\color{red}b$ is any integer such that $\color{blue}{c} \mid a\color{red}b$, then $\color{green}t \mid \color{red}b$.

Using this lemma, since $\color{blue}{c} \mid a\color{green}t$ ($\color{green}t$ is the smallest such positive integer) and $\color{blue}c \mid a\color{red}c$, we have $$\color{green}t \mid \color{red}c$$

Note the distinction in the red and blue colours.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. c|ac since any number will divide a multiple of itself. And since t|b for any b such that c|ab, then by substituting b = c, you get t|c.

Comment: Yes, that's right